# Log scale in pandas scatter_matrix

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

Is it possible to logarithmically scale each of the scatter plots produced by `pandas.scatter_matrix`?  I want the following to work

```
>>> pandas.scatter_matrix(my_dataframe, logy=True, logx=True)
```

Comment: Not that I know of. You could to `pd.scatter_matrix(np.log(my_dataframe))` though.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
axl = pandas.scatter_matrix(my_dataframe)
for i, axs in enumerate(axl):
    for j, ax in enumerate(axs):
        if i != j:  # only the scatter plots
            ax.set_xscale('log')
            ax.set_yscale('log')
```